# Spring boot-hibernate logging on wildfly 10.0.0

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm trying setup logging for hibernate with spring boot. I have deployed a few wars with spring boot dependencies in Wildfly. What I want to do is setup logging sql queries only for one of one war, so i add below lines in specific application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=info
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

But unfortunately logging level have changed for all applications.

Is there any way to accomplish what I need ?

Thanks in advance.